AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to'
tengo este problema: Estoy tratando de realizar un clasificador de audio mediante una base de datos que tengo para proyecto final, solo que me he quedado atorado en esta parte ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? les dejo el código:

Me estoy guiando desde esta página, por si les ayuda también:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/04/guide-to-audio-classification-using-deep-learning/
Cell In[11], line 27
     24 optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(cnn.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
     26 # train
---> 27 train(cnn, train_dataloader,loss_fn, optimizer, EPOCHS,device)
     29 # save model
     30 torch.save(cnn.state_dict(), "C:/Users/migue/Documents/VOZW/modelo/vozwav_class.pth") 

Cell In[10], line 4, in train(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, epochs, device)
      2 for i in range(epochs):
      3     print(f"Epoch {i+1}")
----> 4     train_single_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
      5     print("-----------------------------------------------")
      6 print("Training completed!!")

Cell In[9], line 3, in train_single_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
      1 def train_single_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device):
      2     for input , target in data_loader:
----> 3         input, target = input.to(device), target.to(device)
      5         # loss
      6         predcition = model(input)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to'


El error dice literalmente que input es una tupla corriente de Python y lógicmante no tiene el método to(). falta mucho contexto, pero supongo que  input  debería ser un tensor (torch.Tensor). Sin poder reproducir nada y sin saber que te retorna el dataset es dificil decir que debes hacer, pero o bien tienes una tupla con el tensor dentro y es este el que debes pasar o tienes una tupla de objetos Python "normales" y debes comvertirlos a un tensor antes de pasarlos a la GPU.

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Los errores por si solos no dejan claro cuál es el origen del problema o como resolverlo. usualmente debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta, así como algún ejemplo o explicación de los datos. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderla. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.
